# Mongo - Update each documents of a collection from an Object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

On Meteor server-side method, I inject a `globalPositions` Object with `key=_id` & `value=number` to update all the docs of a `Tasks` collection.

```
globalPositions // {id1: x, id2: y, id3: z…}
```

How to make, in one time on each document of the collection, an update like this

```
Tasks.update({_id: id1}, {$set: {gridIndex: x}});
```

**EDIT**

I found a way, but what about his speed and ingenuity? The objects could be pretty large..

```
Object.keys(globalPositions).map(function(key, index) {
    var value = globalPositions[key];
    Tasks.update({_id: key}, {$set: {gridIndex: value}});
});
```

Comment: You're basically doing a copy from `globalPositions` to `Tasks`. Your loop to update is correct and there isn't a bulk way to do this afaik since each document will receive a unique value. You also have to think about what happens if your server crashes in the middle of this bulk update since you won't know where you left off. How does `globalPositions` get populated?

Comment: @MichelFloyd `globalPositions` is populated in one single time, from a new object index on specific client-side event (reorder of tasks in a grid). Then it's sent to the server through a method call. I have absolutely no idea about the problem of server crashing in the middle of the update: could you tell me more?

Comment: Mongo's probably *not* going to crash in the middle of a large update but unless `gridIndex` is null before the update then you won't know which ones have already been updated. Actually, [bulk.execute](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.execute/#Bulk.execute) might be useful in your context. This allows you to essentially queue up all your updates then execute them in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

By default `update` operation updates single document(applicable for both Meteor and MongoDB). To update all matching documents you need to pass parameter `multi` as `true`.

As per your situation the update looks pretty simple, following snippet should work:

```
Tasks.update({}, {$set: {gridIndex: x}}, {multi: true})
```

**Explanation**: Leave query selector blank to match all documents, then update required fields you wish by `set` operator, finally pass `multi` as `true` to make sure all matching documents are going to be updated.

Comment: But each document must be updated with a value (x, or y, or z...) who belongs to him alone. That's why in the object, the document's `_id` is the `key`. In your response, every document will have `gridIndex: x` no?

Comment: In `MongoDB` every single document has different `_id`. If you try to match `_id: key` it will match only one document. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correct. My question is about updating only one document with the right value, and repeat that on each of them (loop). See my question's editing. Each doc must have his own right `gridIndex value`. Is it clearer?